# needs jquery to take effect after page reloads, fired from previous page on a click

Tags: jquery

needs jquery to take effect after page reloads, fired from previous page on a click
(trigger is in one page and event is in another page)..

```
$(function({
  $('#trigger').click(function(){
    $('#event').addClass('myclass');
  });
});
```

here `#trigger` button is in one page and `#event` is in another page.. I need to add class to `#event` only when `#trigger` button is clicked which links to that page(`<a href="next-page-link" id="#trigger">button</a>`) else if landed on that page with other anchor, i dont need the class to be added to the `#event`..

any idea??

Answer (score 0):

pass a request parameter at the end of the link like its a get request:

/index.html?**source=trigger**

and on the next page check the source parameter and do whatever you want.

[Click for a good tutorial on how to check url params using javascript](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do this. Add a hash parameter to the link that is clicked to go to next page like this:

`<link_to_next_page>#trigger`

Then in the next page use JQuery to parse the query string and see if you have a hash and if so use it to update the `#event` element.

You can use `$(location).attr('hash');` to get the current url's hash. If there is no hash it'll return an empty string.

EDIT: Detailed code:

ok so in the first page you have this link:

`<a href='nextpage#trigger' />`

And in the second page you have the following jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hash = window.location.pathname
  if(hash == 'trigger')
    $('#event').addClass('myclass');
});
```

Comment: var pathname = window.location.pathname;
$('#trigger').click(function(){
if(pathname=='/deluxe/products/'){
$('#event').addClass('myclass');

please mention code in detail.. thanks
}
});

Comment: satisfied? understand?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) for this,capturing the click event on #trigger and then checking if #trigger was pressed on domReady on second page.

Example :

Page 1:

```
$(function({
  $('#trigger').click(function(){
   window.localStorage.triggerClicked = true;
  });
});
```

Page 2:

```
$(function({
  if(window.localStorage.triggerClicked == true){
    $('#event').addClass('myclass');
    window.localStorage.removeItem('triggerClicked');
  }
});
```

Comment: Do I need to call these seperate jquery on seperate individual pages??
can i call these code in common js file?